# Collision is not working properly as3

Tags: actionscript-3

```
var i:Number;

            for (i=0;i<6;i++)
            {

                var brick:Sprite=new Sprite();
                brick.graphics.beginFill(0x02589E);
                brick.graphics.drawRect(0,0,70,7);
                brick.graphics.endFill();
                brick.y=10;
                brick.x=12+(80*i);
                addChild(brick);

            }

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,destroy);

            var ball:Sprite=new Sprite();
            ball.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
            ball.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,7);
            ball.graphics.endFill();
            ball.x=200;
            ball.y=230;
            addChild(ball);
```

.......some code for ball moving.......

```
 function destroy(e:Event):void
            {

                 if(ball.hitTestObject(brick)){
                     removeChild(brick);
                 }
            }
```

When the ball collide with the brick,only the last brick remove.But I want to remove all the brick separately if the ball collide with the brick.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, `brick` is referring to the last instance created in your for loop. What you need to do is store these objects in an array, loop through that array, and check for a collision between each individual brick within that array.

It might look something like this:

```
// Define the array.
var bricks:Array = [];

// Create bricks.
for(var i:int = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    var brick:Sprite = new Sprite();

    brick.y = 10;
    brick.x = 12 + (80 * i);
    brick.graphics.beginFill(0x02589E);
    brick.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 70, 7);
    brick.graphics.endFill();

    addChild(brick);
    bricks.push(brick);
}
```

And then your collision checking code:

```
function destroy(e:Event):void
{
    for each(var brick:Sprite in bricks)
    {
        if(ball.hitTestObject(brick))
        {
            removeChild(brick);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `brick` only refers to a single object. Add all your bricks to an array and then loop through them in your destroy function.